# How to call a plugin function from a page

Tags: plugin-development

I have created a custom plugin to show some details. But issue is that I don't know how to call that plugin function from a page. please help me.

Thanks,

Jyoti

Comment: Have you looked into [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)?

Comment: @Jos Codex is usually considered outdated, your point is still valid. The [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/) has a chapter on shortcodes

Comment: @kero thanks for pointing that out, I had quite carelessly googled the first link for shortcodes.

Comment: @Jos It's the same for me many times, sadly Codex still ranks very high, usually before the new developer guidelines, so I usually add "site:developer.wordpress.org" to my search query